# Testing the difference between multiple outcomes across multiple groups

Tags: anova, categorical-data, kruskal-wallis-test

Data set in R:

```
structure(list(Cohort = c("case1", "case2", "control"), `G0:G0` = c(4, 
183, 341), `G0:G1` = c(0, 0, 5), `G0:G2` = c(3, 1, 0), `G1:G1_hom` = c(7, 
1, 51), `G1:G1_het` = c(4, 0, 211), `G1:G2` = c(6, 0, 0), `G2:G2` = c(3, 
0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to know if there is a significant difference between each cohort's set of groups i.e. G0:G0 compared acrossall three cohorts, G0:G1 etc.

Would an ANOVA be the way to go as this is >2 groups being tested or would you do like a Kruskal-Wallace as I am not sure of the distribution of the data.

The data is a count of patients with a certain type of genotype i.e. a categorical variable but I am unsure if it should follow a normal distribution (I doubt it does).

Many thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have count data with many small values, so the tests you propose aren’t appropriate.

It’s simplest to treat this as a 3 x 7 contingency table representing the cohorts and genotypes, respectively. Each cell contains the number of cases in the corresponding combination of cohort and genotype.

A chi-square test would document whether there are any differences in numbers in any of the cells of the table from the null hypothesis of independence: what you would expect based on each corresponding combinations of overall cohort and genotype proportions. If you use R, it's informative to save the object from `chisq.test()` and examine the observed and "expected" (based on the null hypothesis) counts in each cell.